# When I open Mac TextEdit, it opens all the unsaved files previous open. How do I get it to open with no files?

Tags: macos, applications, text-editor, textedit

I have found many solutions to clearing the recent files in File:Recent menu, but this is a different issue. When you launch TextEdit, it automatically opens all previously open, unclosed (potentially unsaved) files. I sometimes have dozens and dozens. I want them to simply not open sometimes. Otherwise, to close the app you must save or discard all the files, or use Force Quit. When using Force Quit, the whole episode begins again on next open.

Would be great to have a Save All to their default name and location, or close all without saving, or most important, allow app to launch with no prior files loaded.

I've tried eliminating a TextEdit plist, clearing the recent menu, and none have the desired impact of allowing a fresh session of TextEdit with nothing open. Googling has only yielded clearing recent menu, which does nothing regarding opening unsaved files. Force Quit is my current workaround, but still have dozens of assorted files of notes open though not desired to be open.

I must be missing something. I want to open a new app instance with no previous files opened. Thoughts? Or should I change my workflow to make more real-time decisions on the fate of any notes I take in the editor? I may be too old to change my ways ;-)